# How to import csv file (pd.read_csv) from my local laptop into the Google Cloud Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x

[As show i am using VM Jupyter notebook from Google cloud and want to import csv file from my local laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrHz7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click on **File ==> Open** to open a new window with the dashboard view.
Then on the top right, click on **Upload** to upload files from your local laptop.

Comment: Hai Jones, Thank you for your response and you solved my problem. it worked !!

Comment: You are most welcome. Please remind to accept the answer so it can help the community in the future.

Comment: As you are a new contributor maybe I should have give you more details about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.